# MJPEG stream via URL to webcam device on Mac

Tags: macos, video, mjpeg

I have a video device that exposes an MJPEG stream via a URL. For windows there are utility apps that can "create" a system webcam device useable by Skype or any other application based on the URL this video device exposes.

Example: smart phone is broadcasting MJPEG URL. Windows computer can run a utility app to "create" a system webcam based off of the MJPEG stream and then that webcam be used via Skype. The video shown is what the phone is broadcasting.

I'm trying to do the same but for my Mac. I can't seem to find any utility that creates a system webcam from an MJPEG stream. Googling isn't helping either, I'm just not finding a solid solution or anything I recognize as a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with obs-studio and its vlc and virtual camera plugins.

You can add a "Vlc Video Source" and then click "Start Virtual Camera".

If you want to use it as a web-cam I just recommend that you reduce the "Network Caching (ms)" setting in the vlc video source settings as much as possible.

The hard-coded minimal value is 100ms, you can reduce it by changing this line: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/7217671eb0812681a9f83858bb02065b671673e7/plugins/vlc-video/vlc-video-source.c#L1079

There is still significant delay with this method regardless, but it's better than not having it working at all.